# Does Spring XD re-process the same message when one of it's container goes down while processing the message?

Tags: spring-xd

**Application Data Flow:**
JSon Messages--> Active MQ --> Spring XD-- Business Login(Transform JSon to Java Object)--> Save Data to Target DB--> DB.

**Question:**

Sprin-Xd is running in cluster mode, configured with Radis.

Spring XD picks up the message from the Active message queue(AMQ). So message is no longer in AMQ. Now while one of the containers where this message is being processed with some business logic  suddenly goes down. In this scenarios-

1. Will Spring-XD framework automatically re-process that particular message ? what's mechanism behind that?

Thanks,

Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with a Redis transport; Redis has no infrastructure to support such a requirement ("transactional" reads). You would need to use a rabbit or kafka transport.

**EDIT:**

See [Application Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_server_configuration) (scroll down to RabbitMQ) and [Message Bus Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#messagebus).

Specifically, the default `ackMode` is `AUTO` which means messages are acknowledged on success.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Gary.

                                                                                                                           
If we go for Rabbit,

1. Will Spring-XD automatically re-process the message which was partially processed as container went down ?


2. It will be really helpful If you can provide some details or share link explaining the mechanism for re-processing the message  as mentioned in posted question.


Thanks a lot,
Abhi

Comment: Thanks Gary. You comments were really useful. I explored AutoACK option but not sure if it will fulfill above requirement. I read "10.4 Inbound Endpoint Acknowledge Mode " but didn't get much clarity. Can you please advise 1)Once container receives message from the Data Bus, will it send Auto ACK  immediately or after reeving the message and on completion of business rules it will send ACK? 2) What recommendation would you suggest for ACK, should it be Auto ACK or Manual ACK?

Comment: No; there is some confusion there, AUTO in Spring AMQP is not rabbitMQ autoAck; in Spring AMQP, rabbitmq autoAck is called NONE (no ack required). This is to align Spring AMQP more closely with Spring JMS. With AUTO ack, the container will send an ack to RabbitMQ when the module has successfully processed the message. MANUAL ack is rarely needed. NONE means you don't care about lost messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. Your inputs really helped to take the decision.